# Make corresponding image gallery dot active when clicking on image carousel arrows

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

I can't seem to figure this one out Just want to have each dot in this carousel with an 'active' class when you click the arrows to go through the images. Here's my code. Any ideas? Basically just want when you cycle through each image, the dot to be become active via the css

HTML (from a Phoenix template)

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
    <div class="carousel flex flex-row">
      <%= for id <- image_ids() do %>
        <img src={thumb_url(id)} class="rounded-2xl" id="image" />
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
  </div>
  <ul id="dots" class="list-inline dots"></ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
   const GallerySlider: any = {
      mounted() {
        const carousel = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>(".carousel")!;
        const firstImg = carousel.querySelector("img")!;
        const arrowIcons = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(".wrapper i");

    let isDragStart = false;
    let isDragging = false;
    let prevPageX: number;
    let prevScrollLeft: number;
    let positionDiff: number;

    const showHideIcons = () => {
      const scrollWidth = carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.clientWidth;
      arrowIcons[0].style.display =
        carousel.scrollLeft === 0 ? "none" : "block";
      arrowIcons[1].style.display =
        carousel.scrollLeft === scrollWidth ? "none" : "block";
    };

    arrowIcons.forEach((icon) =>
      icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 14;
        carousel.scrollLeft +=
          icon.id === "left" ? -firstImgWidth : firstImgWidth;
        setTimeout(() => showHideIcons(), 60);
      }),
    );

    const autoSlide = () => {
      const position =
        carousel.scrollLeft - (carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.clientWidth) >
        -1;
      if (position || carousel.scrollLeft <= 0) return;

      positionDiff = Math.abs(positionDiff);
      const firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 14;
      const valDifference = firstImgWidth - positionDiff;

      const positionValue =
        positionDiff > firstImgWidth / 4 ? valDifference : -positionDiff;
      carousel.scrollLeft +=
        carousel.scrollLeft > prevScrollLeft ? positionValue : -positionValue;
    };

    //Dragger
    const dragStart = (e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => {
      isDragStart = true;
      prevPageX = "pageX" in e ? e.pageX : e.touches[0].pageX;
      prevScrollLeft = carousel.scrollLeft;
    };

    const dragging = (e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent): void => {
      if (!isDragStart) return;
      e.preventDefault();
      isDragging = true;
      carousel.classList.add("dragging");
      positionDiff =
        "pageX" in e
          ? (e.pageX as number) - prevPageX
          : e.touches[0].pageX - prevPageX;
      carousel.scrollLeft = prevScrollLeft - positionDiff;
      showHideIcons();
    };

    const dragStop = (): void => {
      isDragStart = false;
      carousel.classList.remove("dragging");

      if (!isDragging) return;
      isDragging = false;
      autoSlide();
    };
   
   // Dots code here
    const carouselItem = carousel.getElementsByTagName("div");
    const dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    const dotsChild = document
      .getElementById("dots")!
      .getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (let i = 0; i < carousel.children.length; ++i) {
      dots?.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
      const dot = dotsChild[i];
      dot.classList.add("list-inline-item");
      if (i === 0) dot.classList.add("active");
      dot.setAttribute("id", i.toString());
      dot.innerHTML = i.toString();
    }

    const dnum = "id";
    for (let i = 0; i < carouselItem.length; ++i) {
      carouselItem[i].classList.remove("active");
      if (dnum === null) continue;
      carouselItem[parseInt(dnum)].classList.add("active");
      dotsChild[i].classList.remove("active");
      dotsChild[parseInt(dnum)].classList.add("active");
    }

    carousel.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
    carousel.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
    carousel.addEventListener("touchmove", dragging);

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragStop);
    carousel.addEventListener("touchend", dragStop);
     },
    };
     
export default GallerySlider
```

CSS

```
.dots {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dots li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  line-height: 0.5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  margin: 2px;
}
.dots li.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```